# Traefik, Metallb portforwarding

Tags: traefik, rancher, metallb

I'm having problems portforwarding traefik. I have a deployment in Rancher, where i'm using metallb with traefik to have ssl certs. applied on my services. All of this is working locally, and i'm not seeing any error messages in the traefik logs. It's funny because, at times, i am able to reach my service outside of my network, but other times not.

- I have portforwarded, 80, 433, 8080 to 192.168.87.135
- What am i doing wrong? are there some ports im missing?

[Picture of traefik logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtJwM.png)
[Picture of the exposed traefik loadbalancer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAJVj.png)

Comment: What do you mean by outside of your network?

Comment: As in not locally

Comment: So you mean you are not in the same network? Like in you want to access your service from the internet?

Comment: yes, as in from the internet.

Answer (score 1):

IPv4 specifies private ip address ranges that are not reachable from the internet because:

> The Internet has grown beyond anyone's expectations. Sustained
> exponential growth continues to introduce new challenges.  One
> challenge is a concern within the community that globally unique
> address space will be exhausted.

(source: [RFC-1918 Address Allocation for Private Internets](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918))

IP addresses from these private IP ranges are not accessible from the internet. Your IP address ***192.168.87.235*** is part of the class C private ip address range ***192.168.0.0/16*** hence it is by nature not reachable from the internet.
Furthermore you state yourself that it is working correctly within your local network.

A follow up question to this is: **How can I access my network if it's a private network?**

To access your local network you need to have a gateway that has both an internal as well as a public IP so that you can reach your network through the public IP. One solution could be to have a DNS name thats mapped to the public IP and is internally routed to the internal load balancer IP ***192.168.87.235*** with a reverse proxy.

Unfortunately I can't tell you why it is working occasionally because that would require far more knowledge about your local network. But I guess it could i.e. be that you are connected with VPN to your local network or that you already have a reverse proxy that is just not online all the time.

**Edit after watching your video:**

Your cluster is still reachable from the internet at the end of the video. You get the message ***"Service unavailable"*** which is in fact returned by traefik everytime you wish to access a non-healthy application. Your problem is that the demo application is not starting up after you restart the VM. So what you need to do next is to check why the demo app is not starting. This includes checking the logs of the pod and events of the failing pod.

Another topic I'd like to touch is traefik and what it actually does. First to only call Traefik a reverse proxy, while not false,is not the entire truth. Traefik in a kubernetes environment is an ingress controller. That means it is a reverse proxy configured by kubernetes resources, namely by the "Ingress" object or the "IngressRoute" object. The latter is a custom resource introduced by Traefik itself (read [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/) for further informations) because it introduces andvanced options to configure traefik.
The reason I tell you this is because you actually have two ingress controllers installed in your cluster, ***"Traefik"*** and ***"nginx-ingress-controller"*** and you just need a single one.

Comment: Thank you for the reply :), Traefik is a reverse proxy, while metallb comes with a loadblancer, which is exposed. I have a dns mapped to my global IP, where i have portforwarded my local iP. I made a 10 min video, showing my problem...if you cared to look .https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CjUD5XHHy-8&feature=youtu.be

Comment: @PeterMarcusHoveling I edited the answer with my conclusions.